# How do I set the minimum size of a QML widget?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm using a `QDeclarativeView` to display a QML widget. How do I set the minimum height of the `QDeclarativeView`/widget, so it doesn't get smaller then I want? I'd like to be able to bind it to the minimum size of child widgets, so widgets don't overlap and everything stays properly spaced.

Answer (score 4):

iBelevie's solution is solid, but a little bit of an overkill. QML is to some extent CSS on steroids and supports inline javascript. I hope you now know where this is going :)
Simply define your property as a conditional statement:
`height: (root.height < threshold) ? minHeight: WhateverIsEpressibleInJavaScript`. It is not slick and solid solution, but at least it is a one-liner **inside markup**. I leave it for the reader to contemplate whether it's good or not.

Answer (score 3):

#### Step #1: Define the minimum size in QML

First, in your main widget, create two properties to hold the the minimum width and height:

```
property int minWidth: <whatever>
property int minHeight: <whatever>
```

If you want it based the minimum size of the widget's children, you could do something like this:

```
Item {
    id: root

    property int minWidth: child.minWidth + 40; // Adds a 40px margin
    property int minHeight: child.minHeight + 40; // Adds a 40px margin

    Item {
        id: child
        property int minWidth: <whatever>
        property int minHeight: <whatever>
        anchors.centerIn: root
    }
}
```

#### Step #2: Connect the minimum size in QML to the minimum size of the `QDeclarativeView`

Then, in the class that creates the `QDeclarativeView`, define two slots (`view` is the `QDeclarativeView`):

```
void onMinimumWidthChanged() {
    view->setMinimumWidth(view->rootObject()->property("minWidth").toInt());
}

void onMinimumHeightChanged() {
    view->setMinimumHeight(view->rootObject()->property("minHeight").toInt());
}
```

Then, when you create the `QDeclarativeView`:

```
QDeclarativeView *view = new QDeclarativeView(this);
view->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
view->setSource(/* Whatever */);
QDeclarativeProperty(view->rootObject(), "minWidth").connectNotifySignal(this, SLOT(onMinimumWidthChanged()));
QDeclarativeProperty(view->rootObject(), "minHeight").connectNotifySignal(this, SLOT(onMinimumHeightChanged()));
onMinimumWidthChanged();
onMinimumHeightChanged();
```

Now, the minimum size of the `QDeclarativeView` will be bound to the minimum size as defined in the main QML widget. If you change the minimum size anywhere in QML, the minimum size of the `QDeclarativeView` will change as well.